# Multiplayer VR art gallery using different headsets

Tags: unity, multiplayer, virtual-reality

I'm creating a VR art gallery using Unity3D (like a VR [Museum Views](https://artsandculture.google.com/project/streetviews) with more freedom) and would like to have an environment where 1 or more users can gather together, communicate and move around (similar concept to [SecondLife](https://secondlife.com/) except in this case would be first-person view (by default) with only one room/location and users would be in VR).

From a user perspctive, the initial screen would be a door and the user would have a mini-map and a menu, turned to him/herself, with specific actions.

[image: Seak Claus Winkler's door]

Once inside of the gallery, the users would be able to see others, "walk" or "teleport" to different locations

[image: Gallery]

and see the canvas

[image: Seak Claus Winkler's ICH]

The overall environment is rather simple so I've decided to get feedback from potencial users. Turns out the majority doesn't want to be alone in such environment. So, I've considered adding multiplayer (one of the users could even be guiding the others, which is interesting).

Now, multiplayer makes more sense when we can more inclusive. That's where the problem starts. In this specific case, inclusive is being defined as the possibility of users to be able to be present in the environment using *at least one* of the following devices

- Android Phone (Cardboard)
- Oculus GO
- Samsung Gear VR
- Google Daydream
- Oculus Rift
- HTC Vive

I've done some research and couldn't find someone doing it or a way to do it (considering all of the requirements). If that's possible to do, how can i do it?

One thing I found was that if I didn't want the users to move around and just be watching the gallery like watching a webinar / presentation in different devices, I could use [VR Sync](https://vr-sync.com/) (they basically synchronize video playback on multiple VR devices).

So, at the moment I can either have the environment with just one user at a time and develop the environment for all the different headsets or use VR Sync.

Comment: It sounds more like you'll end up recreating VR-chat, but with art™.

Comment: Didn't know about VR-chat. I can see similarities indeed.

Comment: Problem is that is not inclusive according to the definition given in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is Too General. so i have to give a General answer too. VR is just an input/output system that takes Head Position with Gyroscope and ... and returns resulting view with head mounted screens.

unity basically work for all supported headsets. you just have to change your goal platform to VR to change camera to VR camera. that is all.

what you are looking for is a realTime multiplayer System that players can send they own position and rotation and receive others. realTime Multiplayer or online is based on UDP for real-time and faster connection. unity has many solution for this like photon as easy approach or latest one that has much more freedom and responsiblity to work with. i give you link below:

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer/blob/master/com.unity.transport/Documentation~/TableOfContents.md